# How to restrict android edit text to accept only alphabets and length

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have one edit text. I have set the property android:maxLength="35" to limit the length. It is working fine. But when I use the below code to restrict the edit text to accept only alphabets, I am able to enter more than 35 characters.

```
etLastName.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return src;
                        }
                        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please help me how can I apply both conditions on my edit text.

Answer (score 1):

You can try android:digits property and specify in the XML itself what are the valid characters for you. And for restricting the length use the android:maxLength property as others said too.

Like,

```
 android:digits="ABCDEFGH..."
 android:maxLength=35;
```

However for complex restrictions and validations on EditText InputFilter's are more appropriate. So you are already doing good. :)

I was searching for InputFilter and I found what you want,

```
InputFilter.LengthFilter(int max); //sets the maxlength
```

Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
etLastName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

and set `android:maxLength="35"` to your edittext property in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to the EditText in your layout file:

```
android:maxLength="35"
```